# fopen() in c : segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, malloc

I'm trying to wrap the C library functions **malloc** and **free** to detect whether there is memory leakage in my code. I extend the malloc/free functions by adding to them an fprintf to write to a file the address of the malloc/free and the size.

Compiling this code with gcc or clang **gives a segmentation fault in the fopen() line.**
Here is the command:

`gcc -o mainapp main.c -Wall -Wextra`

I placed the fopen inside the malloc and free function but also get the same issue: **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

I can't find an explanation for the issue.

Here is my complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define __USE_GNU
#include <dlfcn.h>

#define TEST_MEM_LEAK 1 // a value of 1 means to join the memory leak detection, and a value of 0 means not to join

#if TEST_MEM_LEAK

typedef void *(*malloc_t)(size_t size);
malloc_t malloc_f = NULL;

typedef void (*free_t)(void *p);
free_t free_f = NULL;

int malloc_flag = 1;    // It is used to prevent repeated recursion and cannot exit because the printf function will call malloc for memory allocation
int free_flag = 1;
const char* logFileName = "/home/hammamiw/Documents/HeapMonitor/allocs.log";
FILE* fp = NULL;

void initCheck()
{
    fp = fopen("/home/hammamiw/Documents/HeapMonitor/allocs.log", "w");
}

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    if(malloc_flag) { 
        initCheck();  
        malloc_flag = 0;  // Used to prevent printf from causing an error when calling malloc recursively
        void *p = malloc_f(size);
        fprintf(fp, "malloc, %lx, %lu\n", (uintptr_t)p, size);
        //printf("m\n");
        malloc_flag = 1;  // It is used to ensure that the initial value of flag flag is consistent when malloc in this file is called again
        return p;
    } 
    else {
        return malloc_f(size);  // Here, the malloc function in the system library obtained by dlsym is called
    }   
}

void free(void *p) 
{
    initCheck();
    if(free_flag) {
        //initCheck();  
        free_flag = 0;
        fprintf(fp, "F, %lx\n", (uintptr_t)p);
        //printf("f\n");
        free_f(p);
       free_flag = 1;
    } else {
        free_f(p);
    }
}
#endif

int main()
{
#if TEST_MEM_LEAK // the part from if to endif can be divided into function calls
    malloc_f = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
    if(!malloc_f) {
        printf("load malloc failed: %s\n", dlerror());
        return 1;
    }
    free_f = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "free");
    if(!free_f) {
        printf("load free failed: %s\n", dlerror());
        return 1;
    }
#endif
    void *p1 = malloc(10);  //The malloc function in this article will be called first
    void *p2 = malloc(20);
    
    //Here, p2 is not released and there is a memory leak. Judge by checking whether the number of malloc and free times printed is the same
    free(p2);
    free(p1);
    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: the code works well if I use printf instead of fprintf -> prints "f" and "m" at each free and malloc call.

Environment: Ubuntu 22.04, C language, GCC compiler version 11.3.0

Comment: why is this tagged [tag:clang]?

Comment: what does your debugger say?

Comment: `fopen()` will allocate memory, perhaps with `malloc()`. This will cause a recursion with stack overflow.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I removed the clang tag. I kept only c, malloc and linux.
for the debug it stops at fopen and shows "segmentation fault"

Comment: @ensc yes it seems this is the reason of the issue. What do you suggest as a solution

Comment: One thing to be careful of - by using single global flags, your code isn't thread-safe.  If multiple threads were to call `malloc()` or `free()` simultaneously, the global flag values could be incorrect from the view from any one thread.  You could replace `fprintf()` with `write()` and you wouldn't need the flags, but that would complicate your data collection.  You'd have to either write something like fixed-size binary data and post-process it, or you'd have to convert the data to strings without using anything that would call `malloc()`.

Comment: Before reinventing the wheel, read about `valgrind` or `mtrace`

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Issue fixed (as suggested by @ensc and John Zwinck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `malloc_flag` before calling `fopen()`.  Then you will protect against recursion not only via `fprintf()` but also via `fopen()`.

Comment: Yes, by setting 'malloc_flag' to 0 before the calling 'fopen()' in 'initCheck()', and then getback to 1.